# Distorted image texture on curved plane

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, image

I am trying to make a curved TV screen (plane) using the image texture node, but the image texture is distorted on the edges of the tv in perspective view. Although, in orthographic view, it looks like a normal image on a plane.

[image: In perspective view]

Curved along the edges

[image: In orthographic view]

Looks like a normal image on a plane

And also, there are parts of the image texture that are going outside of the assigned faces for the texture.

Would love to see if someone has a solution to the problem, I will provide more information on the nodes or something else if needed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to project the texture from a perspective view and then manually adjust the top and bottom edges to remove their curve. To do this press 1, as you are looking down the Y axis, and press the middle mouse button to exit orthographic view. Select the entire surface and press U then V to project from view. Then open the UV Editor layout. Select all the points on one of the curved edges and straighten them out by pressing S, Y, 0, and do the same to the other curved edge.

[image]